# Mouse and Keyboard freeze on Thunderbolt 3 Dock

Tags: usb, kernel, mouse, freeze, thunderbolt

### Situation

I have a peripheral mouse and keyboard connected to a USB port on a Thunderbolt 3 dock.

```
    Mouse (or keyboard) <---USB---> Thunderbolt 3 dock <---TB3---> Notebook
```

The notebook is a Razer Blade 2019 Advanced with RTX2070 Max-Q, running the NVIDIA 460 driver. The Thunderbolt 3 dock is a HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 dock. All with newest BIOS and firmware upgrades. The issue appears regardless of mouse and keyboard make.

### Issue

The mouse (and keyboard) hangs or freezes after I stopped moving / using it. When I plug it into the USB port of the Thunderbolt 3 dock it works flawlessly until I stop moving or using it. Sometimes I can move a second time but only very shortly.

### Forensics

The logs show nothing. There is nothing indicative compared to plugging the devices into a USB port on the laptop itself. I attached a log to this post at the end.

Kernel version is `5.8.0-48-generic`. I tried disabling any autosuspend options with setting e.g. `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` kernel commandline. I checked `powertop` and set everything to `Bad`. Since the Thunderbolt 3 port is connected to the RTX2070 discrete GPU, I tried the `nouveau` driver and the same issue applies. I removed `tlp` and the issue still applies.

The mouse does not disappear from the device tree when it freezes. I tried to observe differences in the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power` and other files comparing when the device is connected to an internal USB port vs. a USB port on the Thunderbolt 3 dock. I could not find any differences.

I can replicate the behavior without replugging by going into the respective `/sys/bus/usb/devices/7-1/7-1.2` folder and reauthorizing the device, e.g.
`echo 0 > authorized; echo 1 > authorized`. Every time I do so, the mouse can very shortly be used until I stop moving it and then it freezes again.

I tried setting the `level` and `control` and others in the `/sys/.../power` folder to `on`, but it doesn't change anything.

### Others

Other USB devices (e.g. flashdrives) don't have this issue on the USB ports of the Thunderbolt 3 dock. I tried also other HID devices and the issue persists.

The problem does not appear on other non-Linux OSes, e.g. Windows.

The problem appears also on Live USB.

The problem appears also with the `nouveau` driver.

The problem appears on any USB port on the Thunderbolt 3 dock.

The problem also appears with Fedora 33,34.

### Syslog: When replugging the USB mouse

```
Apr 10 15:02:25 blade kernel: [ 1760.207524] usb 7-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.437240] usb 7-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c332, bcdDevice= 3.02
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.437245] usb 7-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.437249] usb 7-1.2: Product: Gaming Mouse G502
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.437252] usb 7-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.437254] usb 7-1.2: SerialNumber: 
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.447749] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G502 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2/7-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C332.0013/input/input61
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.448299] hid-generic 0003:046D:C332.0013: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G502] on usb-0000:09:00.0-1.2/input0
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.450590] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G502 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2/7-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C332.0014/input/input62
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.507664] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G502 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2/7-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C332.0014/input/input63
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.507811] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G502 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2/7-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C332.0014/input/input64
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade kernel: [ 1760.508071] hid-generic 0003:046D:C332.0014: input,hiddev0,hidraw9: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Gaming Mouse G502] on usb-0000:09:00.0-1.2/input1
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade mtp-probe: checking bus 7, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2"
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade mtp-probe: bus: 7, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade boltd[1361]: probing: started [1000]
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade mtp-probe: checking bus 7, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/usb7/7-1/7-1.2"
Apr 10 15:02:26 blade mtp-probe: bus: 7, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Apr 10 15:02:29 blade boltd[1361]: probing: timeout, done: [2863040] (2000000)
```

Comment: I have additional forensics:

If I use `usbhid-dump` with my associated device model, I can reuse the mouse similarly to when I replug it. I tried to observe the power status of the USB bus and indeed it's `runtime_status` switches to `active` for a short time, only to go back to suspended.

Unless, if I repeatedly probe the `runtime_status` again with e.g. `while true: do cat power/runtime_status; done`, which is very wasteful on the CPU.

Comment: I tried setting all the devices' `power/control` like this: echo on | tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control, I tried forcing power on the thunderbolt device, I tried `usbcore` and `usbhid` quirks. I tried by changing the `mousepoll` and kbpoll settings. All didn't help.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question with new information (rearrange as needed for readability), instead of posting comments.

Comment: 1. There is an incomplete sentence in the OP: "I tried the..."
2. Did you try with a different mouse? With a different keyboard? 
Perhaps with wireless mouse/keyboard you can get further hints on the problem, or at least a working case (even if not your target).

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I edited the OP, thanks for mentioning it. As I said, other USB HID devices (mouse, keyboard,...) have the same issue.

Comment: You're headed down a path of sorrow, unfortunately. Thuderbolt is thoughly unreliable and mostly broken under Linux, regardless of your distro.  You'll experience the random USB disconnects, or no functional peripherals after a suspend/wake cycle, etc. and as of this time (May of 2021) there's no provably functioning solution. What you *can* do is get you one of the cheap USB-C dongles (e.g. I have a HooToo HT-UC007) and it will work flawlessly for you, giving you your HDMI port, network, usb, etc. all via the single USB connection to your laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a bigger issue

This apparently can't be answered easily and is indicative of a larger problem with and inside internal systems such as BIOS, drivers and local firmware. Apparently, the issue is widespread also with other combinations of Thunderbolt 3 devices.

The reader might consult these sources for further reference:

- [USB over thunderbolt turns off every once in a while](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1766076) in Ubuntu Launchpad bug database
- [Linux + Nvidia driver + dock station + external monitors](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-nvidia-driver-dock-station-external-monitors/128334) in Nvidia Linux forums.

Answer (score -3):

Ubuntu does not support Thunderbolt 3:

[image: No Thunderbolt Support]

Comment: Probably incorrect.

Comment: Most certainly incorrect. I've been using Thunderbolt 3 since Ubuntu 19.04 (vanilla and MATE) on a pair of Lenovo ThinkPads just fine. Can confirm Thunderbolt is fully operational (on my secondary notebook) with 21.04 as well. Do not have a dock to test USB connectivity with, though ...